# Check if file exists on remote machine. If not, then copy it

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am very new to powershell and was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction.

I was looking to write a script that would help me with the following:

1. I have a file that I need to push to remote machines.
2. I have a list of remote computer names that I wish to check to see if the file exsists.
3. If the file exists and the size and date are the same, then do nothing.
4. If the file does not exist, or the date/size are different, then copy the file.
5. I would also possibly like to write to some sort of log/text file to indicate the status, such as "PC1 - no file found. Copying" or "PC2 - exact file found, nothing copied"

Answer (score 1):

There is powershell script that follows your logic. Destination can be UNC path.

```
$source =  "C:\Tmp\Test.txt"
$destination = "C:\Tmp\Destination\Test.txt"

$TestPath = Test-Path $destination
IF (!$TestPath)
{Copy-Item $source $destination -Verbose
PC1 - no file found. Copying}
ELSE
{
IF (((Get-ChildItem $source).Length -ne (Get-ChildItem $destination).Length) -or ((Get-ChildItem $source).LastWriteTime -ne (Get-ChildItem $destination).LastWriteTime))
{Copy-Item $source $destination -Force -Verbose}
ELSE
{"PC2 - exact file found, nothing copied"}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Robocopy?  You can copy to the local machine if you're an admin with it.

\pcname\c$\path\

You can do differential copying and mirroring if needed.